# How do I obtain the kill signal / message / reason within a script?

Tags: shell-script, scripting, signals, exit, sigtrap

I am using the following trap:

```
trap OnExit EXIT
```

And in my `OnExit` function I would like to capture all the info I can on what happened so I can write it to a log file. Id like to know who, why, how, when etc..

Is any of this possible?

Comment: What do you mean under "etc"? Also, please be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. who** - as another user cannot send signals to your processes, it is most likely that it will be the process owner user (the root user still can, but I don't know a way to find out if root kills your process).

**2. why** - maybe something like this:

```
echo "Why did you interrupted the process?" && read why && echo $why > log
```

(I'm not sure what you mean under why).

**3. how** - as BASH receives the same signal if the user presses `Ctrl + C` or if he sends an interrupt via `kill`, AFAIK it is impossible to find out how exactly did the interrupt happen.

**4. when** - that's easy, use the `date` command:

```
date > log
```

**EDIT:** if you meant determining the signal type under "why" and "how", then see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175647/is-it-possible-to-detect-which-trap-signal-in-bash) Q&A on StackOverflow.

Comment: I think either `why` or `how` was intended to mean "What signal caused the termination?"

Comment: Yes, that might be. Edited answer.

Comment: Yes that is exactly it! I was hoping for some hidden variable i didn't know about but it will have to do. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Which Q&A? Was there suposed to be a link?

Comment: The word "this" is supposed to be clickable. Anyway, here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175647/is-it-possible-to-detect-which-trap-signal-in-bash